# Linux - Store a sql select value in a variable bash

Tags: linux, bash, sqlite

I want to store the value of the sqlite statement in a variable

`backup=$(sqlite3 "/home/miguel/Desktop/SO/ProjetoFinal/Backup_Principal.db" "SELECT periocidade_backup FROM STORAGE WHERE path'$path';")`

But when i echo $backup it returns the following:

sqlite3 "/home/miguel/Desktop/SO/ProjetoFinal/Backup_Principal.db" "SELECT periocidade_backup FROM STORAGE WHERE path='$path';"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is very strange. Are you sure you are running bash (check the output of `ps`) and that you executed exactly the same command you showed us? If yes, then what is your output for `a=$(echo b); echo "$a"` and what is the output of `sqlite3 "/home/mi...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the part of your code `'$path'` is using a single quote which is literal and show exactly as what is in the quotes, which would not use the variable's value. using speech marks like the following should work, `"'$path'"`